# Branch with specific files in git

Tags: python, git, sublimetext3

So,here is my dilemma!I am a novice in python and web development but I have been developing a web app from considerable amount of time like a year by looking at various tutorial and online courses.I learnt about git and immediately started using it as I already had lost my work considerably in past without much dwelling into the specifics and workflow.Now,after a year,my project has gone considerably grown bigger and has 10000's line of html,js and python scattered everywhere.I have been using flask, and utilizing flask blueprint structure in doing so.

My web app is divided into different features and so is the structure.Now,my problem is when I work in the editor - Sublime Text 3 - on a particular feature,I only need to manipulate four folders namely static,templates and views and models.But,presently I have to open the whole project in my editor and its so confusing with 100's of files when I really needed 4 or 5 to work at one time.I really believe there must be a better way to do it as this looks so messy.

It would be really handy if I can branch with these four files,tag them,commit them and work only on those on my editor.Is there a way to do that or I am stuck with the structure for now?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the down vote?Please mention the reason so that I may do it better next time.Simply down voting a question doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

That's not how git is supposed to be used. you have the full app on a branch (let's say master). When you want to work on feature A, you create a new branch starting from master and do the changes you need. It's not supposed to have a branch with only the 4 files you need on that branch. The idea is that in any branch you can star an application to see how everything works together.

I started writing a serie of blog posts/tutorials on git, maybe it helps you (still WIP):

1- http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-init/

2- http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-clone/

3- http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-workflow/